# Get List of all failed SSIS package on a particuar date

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, ssis-2017

Hi everyone is there any way  we  can get list of all failed packages on any particular  date , can we do this with a SQL query ? 
We are using SSIS 2017 .

Comment: Please have a look into https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/88810/what-is-the-query-to-display-the-failed-sql-jobs

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the package is deployed to SSISDB and ran from the catalog, query the `SSISDB.CATALOG.EXECUTIONS` DMV for executions with a status of 4.  Packages with a status of 4 resulted in failure, as specified in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-executions-ssisdb-database?view=sql-server-2017).  Since the `start_time` column is of the `datetimeoffset` date type and I'm assuming you only want to query by the date, not time, that a package failed, this column is cast to a date below in order for it to default to midnight.

```
SELECT EXECUTION_ID
      ,FOLDER_NAME
      ,PROJECT_NAME
      ,PACKAGE_NAME
      ,REFERENCE_ID
      ,REFERENCE_TYPE
      ,ENVIRONMENT_FOLDER_NAME
      ,ENVIRONMENT_NAME
      ,[OBJECT_ID]
      ,[STATUS]
      ,START_TIME
      ,END_TIME
      ,CALLER_SID
      ,CALLER_NAME
      ,SERVER_NAME
      ,MACHINE_NAME
FROM SSISDB.CATALOG.EXECUTIONS
--4 for failed packages
WHERE [STATUS] = 4 AND CAST(START_TIME AS DATE) = '2019-01-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi try this sql query for sql agents jobs [Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-tables/dbo-sysjobhistory-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT sj.name,
        sh.run_date,
        sh.step_name,
        STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 6) +  CAST(sh.run_time as varchar(6)), 6), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':') 'run_time',
        STUFF(STUFF(STUFF(RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', 8) + CAST(sh.run_duration as varchar(8)), 8), 3, 0, ':'), 6, 0, ':'), 9, 0, ':') 'run_duration (DD:HH:MM:SS)  ',
        sh.run_status
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs sj
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory sh
    ON sj.job_id = sh.job_id
WHERE sh.run_status = 0
AND sh.run_date = '20190122'
```

Comment: This won't be specifically SSIS packages that failed, it'll be SQL Agent Jobs that failed. SSIS and SQL Agent are 2 very different things. If the package is called via T-SQL as well (which is very easy to do in SQL Server 201+ with SSISDB) this script will not provide information on these failures.